# Passing data to views in Phil Sturgeon Codeigniter template library

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, codeigniter-3

Installed [Phil Sturgeon Codeigniter Template library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template)

It seems that the library is installed correctly as I can set title with `title()`, `set_partial()` and `set_layout`. And everything is working. But I Can't pass any data.

If I set new title in Controller with `$this->template->title('My Title');`
I can easily get title in any View with `echo $template['title']`

For example, I want to pass a message: 
In View:

```
<?php echo $template['message']; ?>
```

In Controller I try:

```
$this->template->set('message', 'My new mess');
$this->template->build('dashboard');
// I get *Undefined index: message* from View


$data['message'] = ['My new mess'];
$this->template->build('dashboard', $data);
// Same *Undefined index: message*


$this->template->build('dashboard', array('message' => 'My new mess'));
// Even this does not work
```

Using CI 3.
Template config settings regarding parser:

```
$config['parser_enabled'] = FALSE;
$config['parser_body_enabled'] = FALSE;
```

It seems that I miss a small detail.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured it out.

The main confusion for myself was from the documentation itself.
Only the title that is set by the Template with `$this->template->title()` can be called as `$template['title']` in views.

All other data are passed as follows

In Controller:

```
$this->template->set('message', 'My message');
$this->template->build('dashboard');
```

In View just:

```
echo $message
```

Comment: Be aware with 5 years old code and double check all methods in it.

Comment: So far no issues with CI 3.0.6. Actually I was surprised that probably the most popular template library didn't have any updates for 4 years. Though I didn't try it with the CI parser.